# Xpage java code to interact with gmail api

Tags: java, xpages, gmail-api

Using Domino Designer 9.0.1FP3 how can I use Gmail API?

Tried sample Java code from this link https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/java without any luck as follows:

1. Imported necessary gmail api .jar latest version.
2. Installed jre is 8 and setup build path for jre 8 path
3. Complier JRE version is still same which 1.5 by default.

Any help will be appreciated.

This is java agent to interact with gmail api:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

import lotus.domino.*;

import com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.Credential;
import com.google.api.client.extensions.java6.auth.oauth2.AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp;
import com.google.api.client.extensions.jetty.auth.oauth2.LocalServerReceiver;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleClientSecrets;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.javanet.GoogleNetHttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.json.jackson2.JacksonFactory;
import com.google.api.client.json.JsonFactory;
import com.google.api.client.util.store.FileDataStoreFactory;
//import com.google.api.*;
/***/The following lines has error "import can not be resolved". I've imported jar and their sources from gmail .jar file zip***
import com.google.api.services.gmail.*;
import com.google.api.services.gmail.GmailScopes;
import com.google.api.services.gmail.model.*;
import com.google.api.services.gmail.Gmail;





public class JavaAgent extends AgentBase {


    public void NotesMain() {
         /** Application name. */
        final String APPLICATION_NAME =
            "Gmail API Java Quickstart";
        /** Directory to store user credentials for this application. */
        final java.io.File DATA_STORE_DIR = new java.io.File(
            System.getProperty("user.home"), ".credentials/gmail-java-quickstart");

        FileDataStoreFactory DATA_STORE_FACTORY;

        /** Global instance of the JSON factory. */
        final JsonFactory JSON_FACTORY =
            JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance();

        HttpTransport HTTP_TRANSPORT;

        /* Global instance of the scopes required by this quickstart. */
        final List<String> SCOPES =
         //   Arrays.asList(com.google.api.services.gmail.GmailScopes.)//.GMAIL_LABELS);
Arrays.asList(com.google.api.)

        try {
          Session session = getSession();
          AgentContext agentContext = session.getAgentContext();

          // (Your code goes here)

      } catch(Exception e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
       }
   }
```

Comment: Domino 9.0.1 uses Java 1.6. Are you using XPages or a Java agent? Please add some more details including code that shows what you have tried.

Comment: I'm using java agent to interact with gmail api.

Comment: The added code is from https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/java

Comment: See this article for info on how to have your Java agent run using Java 1.6: http://www.codestore.net/store.nsf/unid/BLOG-20111010-0602

Comment: To run gmail api the compiler compliance level s 1.7 or higher as this link says https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/java. How can set up Domino designer compliance to 1.7?

Comment: You can't. Domino uses Java 1.6

Comment: Is there any work around? Tried,adding JRE system library path to project specific properties., JavaCompilerTarget=1.8/CurrentJavaVersion etc, suggestions below, but no luck. The import java.nio.file.File still shows resolution error with all the changes made.

Comment: Only possible workaround is to compile the Gmail API for Java 1.6.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Installed jdk1.7.079
2. In project properties->Java Build Path set it up as JRE System Library(jdk1.7.079)

No more compilation error.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, you need to make sure that the API can actually run on a Java 1.6 as Per mentions.

You can add the jar(s) to your Domino in several ways:

**1. In the JVM ext/lib directory**

This works fine - it is just a pain to maintain as everthing needs to be done in the file system (also in your Domino Designer). This works for XPages as well as agents.

**2. Attach the jar to your agent/script library**

This only applies to code running in agents (or webservices). However, there is a memory leak which occurs every time the code is called (and the jar is detached internally). So don't use this one!

**3. Add the jar as a jar design element**

This should also work - though I haven't got much experience with it. I fear the same issues as with the element above - but has no evidence on that. So you are probably fine using this - will only work for XPages.

**4. Add the jar as a plugin**

You can wrap the jar into an OSGi plugin and deploy it server wide (2 and 3 above only makes the jar available to the NSF the jar is inside). This is by far my preferred way. I have written an [article about the details](http://www.dalsgaard-data.eu/blog/wrap-an-existing-jar-file-into-a-plug-in/) that can help you on the way.

/John

Comment: Also, if installing the jar in the NSF, if you get a NoClassDefFoundError, try changing security settings to allow all permissions in java.policy. If that solves the problem, option 4 is the way to go. Domino's Java security is copied from Websphere and does not delegate as much to the Domino server as it should.
Java 8 will be coming to Domino in the next release, probably early next year. The Mac install released recently already includes some Java 8 files, which proves that's where IBM are looking.

Comment: Exactly, you will have the permissions issue. You can work around this if you use option 4 - see: http://www.dalsgaard-data.eu/blog/elevating-permissions-for-your-third-party-jar/ :-)

Comment: I don't have any permission errors. Most errors are related to classes and methods in .gmail api such as "CalendarSample cannot be resolved to a type"

Comment: ... and how did you add the jars to be used by your application?

Comment: Added .jars using agent's archive feature means imported .jar file as archive in agent it self

Comment: Hmmmm.... that means that you use what I call option 2. There seems to be a problem with your class path... - but due to the reasons I mentioned above I would go for option 1 - or option 4 - and recode as an XAgent...

Comment: Just saw the comments about JVM version under your original question. You should have read and carried out the first line in my response... :-)